# Compile node projects without using sudo

Tags: unix, permissions, node.js

I feel like this is more of a unix question, but I'm looking to compile [node](http://nodejs.org/) projects without using the sudo command each time.

Example:

`$ node server.js`

Results in the following error:

```
node.js:63
    throw e;
    ^
Error: EACCES, Permission denied
....
```

Is there any way to permanently give node root access?

Thanks!
Matt

Comment: Where is the server.js file stored?  What are the permissions on the file, and its containing directory?  Where does the result need to go?  Why is it restricted to root (there could be good reasons, but they are more likely not good)?  Make sure that you can write in the directory where you're doing the 'compilation'; if you can't, copy the material to somewhere that you can write. You might still need root privileges to install the results - but that depends on a lot of policy decisions (where the code goes, who has to own it, etc). What are the implications if you end up owning everything?

Comment: Oh ok - that's a good point Jonathan. I'll make the folder readable and writeable - thanks!

Comment: FWIW: The node v0.2.5 source builds on MacOS X 10.6.5 with the system provided GCC (4.1.2) but not with GCC 4.5.2.  I chose to install the software in $HOME/Software/node using "`./configure --prefix=$HOME/Software/node`" (so, if it was going to survive, I'd have to add $HOME/Software/node/bin to my PATH, or add a symlink to $HOME/Software/node/bin/node to a directory already in my PATH).  No root privileges used.  One other oddity: you compiled server.js but the error message mentions node.js - is that normal?

Answer (score 0):

Root has permanent root access, so just become root.

```
$ sudo su
```

Or:

- [Install node.js without using sudo](http://increaseyourgeek.wordpress.com/2010/08/18/install-node-js-without-using-sudo/)
- Double-check that your directories you are working in are actually writable by a non-root user.

Comment: Does that mean I'd have to do this every time I open the terminal? I'm looking for a system-wide solution.

Comment: No: don't do anything as root that isn't compulsory.  Do as little as possible as root!